# How to cache/save custom class object in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to save `ArrayList<CustomClass>`-object to somewhere in Android storage to retrieve quickly and display data in it.

Is this possible or not? If yes, then which technique will be suitable, SQLite or external storage?

Comment: why don't use sharepreferences provided in android?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

example.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String title;
    public String startTime;
    public String endTime;
    public String day;

    public boolean classEnabled;


    public MyClass(String title, String startTime, boolean enable) {
        this.title = title;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.classEnabled = enable;
    }

    public boolean saveObject(MyClass obj) {   
        final File suspend_f=new File(SerializationTest.cacheDir, "test");

        FileOutputStream   fos  = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos  = null;
        boolean            keep = true;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(suspend_f);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            keep = false;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (oos != null)   oos.close();
                if (fos != null)   fos.close();
                if (keep == false) suspend_f.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) { /* do nothing */ }
        }

        return keep;
    }

    public MyClass getObject(Context c) {
        final File suspend_f=new File(SerializationTest.cacheDir, "test");

        MyClass simpleClass= null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream is = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(suspend_f);
            is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            simpleClass = (MyClass) is.readObject();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            String val= e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)   fis.close();
                if (is != null)   is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) { }
        }

        return simpleClass;  
    }
```

and calling from activity

```
if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyCustomObject");
else
    cacheDir= getCacheDir();
if(!cacheDir.exists())
    cacheDir.mkdirs();

MyClass m = new MyClass("umer", "asif", true);
boolean result = m.saveObject(m);

if(result)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved object", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error saving object", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   

MyClass m = new MyClass();
MyClass c = m.getObject(this);

if(c!= null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Retrieved object", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error retrieving object", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

dont forget to use write_external_storage permissions in manifest file.

Comment: and dont use context in it otherwise nonserializable exception will be raised.

Comment: From where i can get the class SerializationTest??

Comment: SerializationTest is just a reference to the directory he is using. You will want to get that from Android depending on your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This problem isn't really android specific. I mean if you know how to serialize your data either via java.io.Serializable or you have a custom persistence format, you just need to know where to store it.

You can grab a file on the local device via

```
FileOutputStream stream = null;
try{
   stream = mContext.openFileOutput("name.data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   ObjectOutputStream dout = new ObjectOutputStream(stream);
   dout.writeObject(myArrayList);
   dout.flush();
   stream.getFD().sync();
} catch(IOException e) { //Do something intelligent
} finally {
   stream.close();
}
```

You will have to use openFileInput() later to read the data back.

Or you can grab External Storage. This is similar however you have to guarantee that it even exists. Like is the external storage connected and even able to be written to. Since you are writing a data structure here and usually external storage is world readable I don't think this is a good idea for your intended purposes (just from what you have put so far).

If your data is structured and is going to be queried many times and it might be rather big to always load up then consider using the sql lite tools that are part of the OS. However I am assuming you don't need this either as a simple list is just that, a linear structures which you could probably seek through in a file (assuming it is less than 1MB of data :)

Comment: if you use context then serializable throws error notSerializable exception because context is not serializable. yes idea is same but without using context. thanks.

Comment: Like I said, I am making the assumption you had a serializable object. I am not saying serialize the context. I am saying serialize the contents of the list which you have not described. You shouldn't ever need to persist a context anyways.

Answer (score -1):

This issue can be solved by singleton class [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in which you can set/get any object eg arrayList in any time. If you used Android Service then this solutuion is not suitable.
Perhaps the solution to your problem can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).