# Android Canvas - Whiteboard

Tags: android, store, android-canvas

I am trying to create a canvas in Android where we can use it as a white board and draw on the canvas.

Once some thing has been drawn on the canvas i want to store the canvas so that it can be drawn again on another device or retrieved later when u start the application. i dont wanna store it as am image either.

Whats the best solution to store the things on the canvas ?

[image]

Comment: Why do you not want to store it as an image?

Comment: @Felix so that i can send it to other mobile and redraw it and use it for further changing

Comment: 1) You can easily send an image to another device; 2) You can easily draw the image to a canvas to allow further editing.

Comment: And if different screen sizes is an issue, you can either just scale the saved bitmap, or look into [vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics).

Comment: Felix: can u tell me exactly how to draw on the canvas from an image ? or point me to what i should use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possibilities besides saving it as an image:

1. Save the canvas as an object to phone storage. Then you could either send that file to another device or load that file when your activity is restarted.
2. Save the key presses every time a user touches the screen(and something should be drawn).

Check out this link on how to save files: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Thanks. Emiam,, what kind of Object should i store it as ? will it be a file ? i am using Bluetooth Socket and Server Socket to send data to the connected mobile.

Comment: Yes it will be a file. You can save any object you like. If you want to go with option number 1, you can actually save it as a Canvas object and also read it as a Canvas object. This will actually enable you to call canvas methods like restore()(and restoring sucessfuly to the last save()) you did before writing your Canvas to a file. If you want to go with option number 2, you can write a custom class that saves all the keypresses and just save that object.

Comment: Thanks a lot will try it and get back to you. Just to understand how to handle the diff screen sizes,, any idea ?

Comment: Well that's a large topic. Basically, you need to calculate every measure based on width and height of the device that runs your program. this.getWidth() and getHeight() are useful.

Comment: Hey Buddy. Sorry to trouble you again. I am not able to understand how to convert an object into a file and then send it. Could you tell me which format i will have to use ?

Comment: As for how to save an object to a file, check out the accepted anwser here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546201/how-to-cache-save-custom-class-object-in-android I don't know how to send a file.

Comment: You don't have to save it as an object. Just save the co-ordinates. Thereby you can redraw. It is also very light. No serialization / deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

When drawing, draw into a bitmap-backed canvas:

```
private Bitmap bitmap;
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    // perform all drawing into bitmapCanvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Then, you can save your bitmap using [`compress`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) and load it using [`BitmapFactory.decodeFile`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) or other decode methods in the `BitmapFactory` class.

Comment: Thanks Felix.. just a quick question.. size of the image vs size of an object (as from the other answer) which will be better to in terms to transfer and size ?

Comment: It depends. If there are a lot of drawing operations the bitmap will be smaller. If there are few, the bitmap **may** be larger (it depends on what the image actually contains). Also, PNGs are much more flexible -- you can read them pretty much anywhere. Serialized Java objects and even JSON objects can suffer from deprecation / decoding errors (i.e. if your object structure changes).

Comment: okie. Thank you :) let me try to implement this and let you know :)