# use same object during app run

Tags: java, android, object

I have an application and I want to use the same object in different activities in the app.

I tried make a  class that I write as application in the manifest file, and In this class I put static getter and setter.
But I found out that not all the time this class run..
their is another way do to that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

You can use preferences and save your object there.

```
// Fetch the strings from your object to this array
String[] strings = new String[] { "String1", "String2"};
// Convert the array to a string set 
Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(strings));
// Save to preferences
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.edit().putStringSet("MyStrings", stringSet).apply();
```

Then fetch the preference and read back the strings.

Comment: my problem with this is that when I pause the app this class clear and start again.and if the app stop in another activity the resume will be not with the same order..
I want to save the object also if I pause the app.

Comment: @Alon what's the type of the object?

Comment: my object.. contain strings

Comment: Are you using Fragments?

Comment: this solution save the object.. so in every time I change the object I have to save it again.If the user close the app I dont want the object to be saved.Only on same run time.. if the user pause so it's not influence the object.

Comment: @Alon save it at `onPause` of each activity that modifies this object.

Comment: ok. I thought that their is better way. like an activity that the system does not delete.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the so called [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Example)

Here's a basic implementation:

```
public class MySingleton {

  private static MySingleton mySingleton;

  public MySingleton() {}

  public static MySingleton getInstance() {
      if (mySingleton == null) {
          mySingleton = new MySingleton();
      }
      return mySingleton;
 }

}
```

Now from any activity you can always access that one object by calling `MySingleton.getInstance()`

Comment: I'm sorry. Your question wasn't pointing to the problem of onPause causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

If your application can stop at some time, I think you need to keep this object in database or on disk like serializable object(example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553318/1652236).
And get it in different activities or where you need it.

If it just string object, you can put it in shared preferences and get in different activities.

About database you can find a lot of examples in internet.